# can not use gdb debug mac app

Tags: macos, gdb

I used homebrew installed gdb, and created code sign for it. It seems I have installed it completed. But when I use gdb command to debug the app in */Applicaions*, it always prompted me *no such file or directory*, I have no idea about it. My system is 10.9.4, and GDB version is 7.7.1.

Wait for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

GDB does not automatically load application bundle directories. You need to give it the path to the main Mach-O executable. Something like `/Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/MacOS/...`.

I don't know what the main executable for `Reveal.app` is named, but if it is named `Reveal` your command would look like this.

```
gdb /Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/MacOS/Reveal
```